# How to make quiz questions appear one at a time after clicking next in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So i've been trying to build a quiz app with a feature that when a user clicks a button called "next" the next question appears in place of the current one.
I'm fetching questions from another Js file which has the questions stored as an array of objects.

Initially i had a variable "i" which was initialized to 0 and i was planning to just increment it till i reach the total number of questions.

But how do i re-render that div when i increment "i". I'm trying to do this with vanilla Js.

Here's the code for the div.

```
div.innerHTML = `
    <h1>${questions[i].name}</h1>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="radio" id="0" name="option" value="0">
        <label for="0">${questions[i].options[0].title}</label><br>

        <input type="radio" id="1" name="option" value="1">
        <label for="1">${questions[i].options[1].title}</label><br>

        <input type="radio" id="2" name="option" value="2">
        <label for="2">${questions[i].options[2].title}</label><br>

        <input type="radio" id="3" name="option" value="3">
        <label for="3">${questions[i].options[3].title}</label><br>

        <p id="message"></p>

        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <button id="nextQuestion">Next</button>
</form> 
`

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```
document.getElementById("nextQuestion").addEventListener("click", (e)=> {

    e.preventDefault()

    if(i<questions.length){
        i++;
        // NEED TO DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
    else {
        alert("You've reached the last question.")
    }
})
```

EDIT >>>>>>>>>>>>

Thanks for the response.
So i was trying to think of something and ended up doing exactly what you told but now im stuck with another issue.

Now my next button works properly but when i submit on the first question it works properly and tells me if the answer is correct or not and then when i click next i get the next question but then if i try to submit it reloads the page. Even though i've used e.preventDefault() it reloads it. How do i deal with this?

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", (e)=>{

    e.preventDefault()

        let msg = document.getElementById("message");
        var correctAns = questions[i].answer; 
        
        if(document.querySelector('input[name="option"]:checked') === null){
            msg.innerHTML = "Select an option to proceed."
        } else {
            let userAns = document.querySelector('input[name="option"]:checked').value;
    
            if(correctAns === userAns){
                msg.innerHTML = "Correct"
            } else {
                msg.innerHTML = "Incorrect"
            }
    
            document.getElementById("0").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("1").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("2").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("3").disabled = true;
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to render the HTML content of the question each time the index is updated, so you should throw the rendering logic into a function and call it each time you increment the question.

Also, if you know you are on the last question, you can change the text of the next button to "Finish" or render a different button in its place.

Lastly, you will want to clean-up any event listeners you associated to the DOM before replacing the content or you will have memory leaks.

```js
const quizEl = document.querySelector('.quiz');
const questions = [{
  name: 'How many inches in a foot?', answer: '2',
  options: [{ title: '3' }, { title: '6' }, { title: '12' }, { title: '36' } ]
}, {
  name: 'How tall is the Eiffel Tower?', answer: '1',
  options: [{ title: '308m' }, { title: '324m' }, { title: '352m' }, { title: '463m' } ]
}];
let currentQuestion = 0;
let submitted = false;

const renderQuestion = () => {
  submitted = false;

  // Clean-up since we are removing the DOM
  removeClickListener(quizEl.querySelector('#nextQuestion'), handleNext);
  removeClickListener(quizEl.querySelector('#submit'), handleSubmit);

  const question = questions[currentQuestion];
  const isLast = currentQuestion === questions.length - 1;

  quizEl.innerHTML = `
    <h1>${question.name}</h1>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="radio" id="0" name="option" value="0">
        <label for="0">${question.options[0].title}</label><br>

        <input type="radio" id="1" name="option" value="1">
        <label for="1">${question.options[1].title}</label><br>

        <input type="radio" id="2" name="option" value="2">
        <label for="2">${question.options[2].title}</label><br>

        <input type="radio" id="3" name="option" value="3">
        <label for="3">${question.options[3].title}</label><br>

        <p id="message"></p>

        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        <button id="nextQuestion">${!isLast ? 'Next' : 'Finish'}</button>
    </form> 
  `;

  // Re-associate the listener
  addClickListener(quizEl.querySelector('#nextQuestion'), handleNext);
  addClickListener(quizEl.querySelector('#submit'), handleSubmit);
}

const addClickListener = (btn, listener) => {
  if (btn) btn.addEventListener('click', listener);
};

const removeClickListener = (btn, listener) => {
  if (btn) btn.removeEventListener('click', listener);
};

const handleNext = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const msg = document.getElementById('message');
  
  if (document.querySelector('input[name="option"]:checked') === null) {
    msg.innerHTML = "Select an answer to proceed."
    return; // Exit from function.
  }
  
  if (!submitted) {
    msg.innerHTML = "Please submit your answer before proceeding."
    return; // Exit from function.
  }
  
  if (currentQuestion < questions.length - 1) {
    currentQuestion++;
    renderQuestion();
  } else {
    alert("You've reached the last question.");
  }
};

const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const msg = document.getElementById('message');
  const ans = document.querySelector('input[name="option"]:checked');

  if (!ans) {
    msg.innerHTML = "Please select an answer."
    return; // Exit from function.
  }

  const question = questions[currentQuestion];
  const correctAns = question.answer;
  const userAns = ans.value;

  if (correctAns === userAns) {
    msg.innerHTML = "Correct"
  } else {
    msg.innerHTML = "Incorrect"
  }

  document.getElementById("0").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("1").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("2").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("3").disabled = true;
  
  submitted = true;
};

renderQuestion();
```

```css
#message { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="quiz"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please look at the edit?

Comment: It's all done thanks. Fixed the edit part too.

Comment: @Parth I updated my code to include submission handling. I added various messages to describe what is required as well.